# Running a task on private queue and returning callback

Tags: ios, xcode7, grand-central-dispatch

My method runs its code in a private queue and upon completing, will call the callback passed in.  Is there a need to check if the callback passed in is intended to be run from the main queue?

e.g.

```
- (void)doSomethingWithCalback:(void(^)())callback {
    dispatch_async(self.privateQueue, ^{
    // Should I make sure this gets dispatched 
    // to a main thread if it was passed in from a main thread?
        if (callback) callback();
    });
}
```

Should I do something like the following:

```
    - (void)doSomethingWithCalback:(void(^)())callback {
        BOOL isMainThread = [NSThread isMainThread];
        dispatch_async(self.privateQueue, ^{
            if (callback) {
               if (isMainThread) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_thread, callback); 
               }
               else {
                 callback();
               }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I do not like the proposed code, because now your behavior changes depending upon which queue you called it from. I'd suggest dispatching it to the main queue or not. Or, if you need more flexibility, you can, as RyanR suggested, provide a parameter to the method to specify which queue to use.

Comment: I figure if you are calling it from main thread code, chances are you won't expect things to come back running in a background thread instead.  Providing an onQueue parameter seems like exposing too much of an implementation detail that has nothing to do with the task at hand.

Comment: I understand your intent, but if you're running it from some other thread, the completion handler will now be called on some unknown thread, neither main thread nor the thread it was called from. Personally, I'd be inclined to dispatch it back to the main queue or don't. Your "sometimes main thread" approach is only more confusing, IMHO, and certainly non-standard. And if you want the flexibility to specify, then add a parameter.

Comment: Not sure why the thread thing is an issue - we only care about queue (specifically, whether the code should be on main queue or not), no? If you call the method from a view controller, you would expect callback to be run on main queue because you might do UI update there.  Otherwise you don't care.

Comment: Agree - that's really my point though, the user shouldn't have to care what queue will be used, hence no argument will be provided.  We are simply taking the safe route of making sure code calling from main thread will be treated with caution and have the callback run there as well - because as a user, you certainly won't think that your callback will be run in a background queue instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102845/discussion-between-rob-and-boon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't prescribed anywhere, if you look at the Cocoa API, you'll see three common patterns:

1. **Main thread:** Completion handlers which explicitly specify that the main queue will be used. For example, refer to the `CLGeocoder` [asynchronous query methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:), in which "Your completion handler block will be executed on the main thread."
2. **Arbitrary queue:** Completion handlers where you have no assurances regarding which queue the code will be run. For example, if you use `requestAccessForEntityType` of `CNContactStore`, [the documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CNContactStore/requestAccessForEntityType:completionHandler:) "The completion handler is called on an arbitrary queue."
3. **Specified queue:** Completion handlers where you can specify which queue to use. For example, if you use `[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:queue:]`, you can specify which queue will be used for for delegate methods and callback blocks/closures. (But, as an aside, if you don't specify a queue, it uses one of its own devising, rather than defaulting to the main queue.)

The pattern you propose, though, doesn't follow any of these informal conventions, but instead sometimes uses the main thread (if you happen to call it from the main thread), but sometimes using some arbitrary queue. I don't see a compelling need to introduce a new convention in this situation.

I'd suggest picking one of the above approaches and then make it clear in the published API. For example, if you're going to use a `privateQueue`:

```
@interface MyAPI : NSObject

/// Private queue for callback methods

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t privateQueue;

/// Do something asynchronously
///
/// @param callback  The block that will be called asynchronously.
///                  This will be called on the privateQueue.

- (void)doSomethingWithCallback:(void(^)())callback;

@end

@implementation MyAPI

- (void)doSomethingWithCallback:(void(^)())callback {
    dispatch_async(self.privateQueue, ^{
        if (callback) callback();
    });
}

@end
```

Or

```
@interface MyAPI : NSObject

/// Private queue used internally for background processing

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t privateQueue;

/// Do something asynchronously
///
/// @param callback  The block that will be called asynchronously.
///                  This will be called on the main thread.

- (void)doSomethingWithCallback:(void(^)())callback;

@end

@implementation MyAPI

- (void)doSomethingWithCallback:(void(^)())callback {
    dispatch_async(self.privateQueue, ^{
        if (callback) { 
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                callback();
            });
        }
    });
}

@end
```

Note, whichever convention you use, I'd suggest using `///` comments or `/** ... */` comments in your headers so that when you use the method in your code, that you can see the queue behavior shown in the quick help panel on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You should either specify what queue your API method `-doSomethingWithCallback:` will use when executing the callback, or allow the consumer of your method to pass in the queue they want it executed on, like so:

```
/// callback will be executed on the queue passed in to onQueueOrNil.
/// If onQueueOrNil is nil, it will be executed on the main queue
- (void)doSomethingWithCallback:(void(^)())callback onQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)onQueueOrNil {
    dispatch_async(self.privateQueue, ^{
        if (callback){
            if(!onQueueOrNil) {
                onQueueOrNil = dispatch_get_main_queue();
            }
            dispatch_async(onQueueOrNil, callback);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Requiring callback to specify the queue seems like a lot of work.  What about checking for main thread, added an example.

Comment: FWIW, if I wanted to do the above, I might lose the `if` statement and just do `dispatch_async(onQueueOrNil ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), callback);`.

Comment: Keep it simple and require an explicit queue parameter. Force the client developers to take responsibility and make a choice. If you support nil and use main queue by default in a complex project, it can lead to excessive trampolining to the main thread. Simplify your life and REQUIRE the queue.

Comment: Also better to put the callback as the last parameter so that code is Swift-friendly! (i.e. postfix block argument in Swift)